# meteo.js:21 Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, syntax-error

I have a problem in my code I do not see the weather API appear in my code

> Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function meteo.js:21

```js
if (WithIP) {
  const ip = await fetch('https://api.ipify.org/?format=json%27')
    .then(resultat => resultat.json())
    .then(json => json.ip);

  ville = await fetch("http://api.ipstack.com/json/' + ip + '?access_key=' + access_key")
    .then(resultat => resultat.json())
    .then(json => json.city);

} else {
  ville = document.querySelector('#ville').textContent;
} 

{
  const meteo = await fetch('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Marseille&appid=33119b4a3fa1ad278805578d27ea15de&lang=fr&units=metric%27')
    .then(resultat => resultat.json())
    .then(json => json)
```

Comment: As the error says. You can only use `await` in an `async` function -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quote from Mozilla Developers :

> An async function can contain an await expression that pauses the execution of the async function and waits for the passed Promise's resolution, and then resumes the async function's execution and returns the resolved value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `await` in an `async` function - to avoid making your whole code an `async` function, use IIFEs like so:

```
const ip = (async () => await fetch('https://api.ipify.org/?format=json%27'))();
```

Because you're still using `.then` chaining, you could just remove the `await` part completely and just use `.then` for continuity.

```
fetch('https://api.ipify.org/?format=json%27').then(resultat => resultat.json()).then(...);
```